# How do I get the text from a button after clicking it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get the text of the button clicked to compare it to a string.

```cs
public void clicked()
{

    Debug.Log("Timer done");
    secondsLeft = 0;
    timerOn = false;

    questionUI.SetActive(false);
    Paused = false;
    //turns off the question screen

    string answer = GetComponentInChildren<TMPro.TMP_Text>().ToString();
    if (questions[0] == answer)
    {
        PlayerQuests.points += 1000;
    }

}
```

This is the code I made which the button runs after being clicked. This should get the text inside the button which is a `TextMeshProUGUI` and compare it to another string.

Comment: what is the type of your `questions[]`?

Answer (score 1):

If you add `using TMPro;` at the top of your class, you should be able to get the text of the `TextMeshProUGUI` component by writing:

```
var answer = GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text;
```

Comment: `TMPro.TMP_Text` , OP used would work same

Comment: You're correct! Since `TMP_Text` is the parent class :)